# What can you get from submitting an abstract?

Tags: conference, abstract

I work for a technical company at the interface between engineering practice and research. Since we have to deal with academia on a daily basis, I have seen many calls for "Abstract submission". Generally these calls are associated with some sort of academic conference that is focused on a particular topic. It is also subject to deadlines and regulations. Several universities, research institutions and even private/public entities might be participating at these conferences.

My question is this: What can you actually *get* from submitting an abstract? Why do these conferences even request abstract submission? What do *they* get from it? Why are abstract submissions important and why do people do them?

Comment: In addition to what's already explained in the answers, let me add that many conferences print a booklet of abstracts and give each registered participant a copy of it. That helps the participants decide which talks to attend.  (For conferences with multipage abstracts, what I called a booklet is really a full-sized book.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You submit an abstract to a conference if you would like to give a talk there. The abstract is then used to determine whether or not you get that chance (based on how interesting/relevant/sound the abstract is judged for that particular conference). So for the conference, this lets them filter (a bit) the talks that get presented there, for the author, this is the prerequisite for being allowed to give a talk.

Giving a talk at a conference is a means for a researcher to disseminate their research ideas and to advertise themselves. Discussions following a talk can lead to future collaborations, and giving the right talk at the right time can lead to eg a postdoc position.

"Talks given" is also a typical category on a CV, so even beyond the immediate talk, the fact that you gave the talk can be beneficial in competing for jobs.

Comment: So basically thats it? A talk? What can the talk bring you as a researcher? I understand it makes the conference more interesting but is it also an opportunity for networking or applying for research positions?

Comment: @user32882 I've added a comment on why people might want to give talks.

Comment: "What can a talk bring you as a researcher?"  In some branches of science, conferences are the main places where research is published.

Comment: Another benefit of giving a talk is that it lets you see much clearer what issues there still are to address, and what the strengths and weaknesses of your idea are.

Comment: @GEdgar but in these fields conference talks do not require a abstract to be submitted, but rather a whole paper before the decision is made as to if to accept. (At least that is true for CS and for Signal Processing)

Comment: @user32882 "Giving talks" (and listening to them) is the main formal activity that takes place at a scientific conference. That's why the conference exists at all - the talks aren't just an interesting sideshow!

Comment: @LyndonWhite: That's not true in other fields. Most stuff presented at e.g. CHEP2016 will only be published as proceedings and it does not require writing a paper beforehand, just an abstract.

Comment: @user32882: Scientific Conference are not like sales conference where vendors present their stuff.

Comment: @Marianne013 interesting. So is it the case that for high energy physics conference publications are considered as valid as journal publications? (as it is for large parts of CS). It seems a bit odd to be publishing papers that were accepted based only on the peer review of the abstract -- not the paper itself.

Comment: @LyndonWhite High energy physics is not one of those fields where conferences are the main avenue through which research is published. And accordingly(?), conference submissions are not considered as valid as journal publications. Actually, in HEP one does not generally submit a full paper to a conference; we submit an abstract, a slideshow (for the talk), and perhaps afterward a proceedings which is a ~4-page written summary of the research described in the talk.

Comment: Ergo as HEP is not a field where most research is published in conferences. Thus is not a counter example to my claim that in fields where conferences *are* the main venue (eg CS) a Paper is required for acceptance, not merely an abstract

Comment: @LyndonWhite CHEP is about Computing in High Energy Physics, not HEP itself. While HEP proper works as David Z. explained, papers in the Computing part are rare, Proceedings are the main form of attributing recognition to an idea and generally you are assigned talks on your abstract and  write the proceedings afterwards.

Answer (score 18):

Following up the comment - giving a talk is not just a CV line. For most academic researchers, access to funding to attend a conference depends on being a presenter at that conference. So giving a talk is essentially the ticket to hearing what other people are working on, identifying potential collaborators, and keeping up to date.

Journal papers are not really sufficient, publication tends to be slow (though in some disciplines, initiatives like ArXiv is correcting that) and talking with someone is often better than reading a report to understand what they have done. Personally, I always find at least a few talks at conferences that are interesting and give me new ideas but I probably wouldn't have read the paper because it wouldn't have appeared in any of my searches.

Answer (score 6):

Writing an abstract to a conference by itself will only give you the chance to speak at that conference. As others noted, you can put the conference talk on a CV and access funding to go to the conference because your talk is accepted. Some institutions and even grant agencies would count the number of your talks and conference papers -- each for its own abhorrent reasons.

But, there are many other benefits one can get from giving the talk.

- early career scientists (PhD students and young postdocs) get a chance to present their own research and practice for thesis defenses, future job interviews, etc. One gains a lot of confidence from giving a good (or even decent) talk.
- one learns to present their research subject to different types of audiences, depending on the conference. I've often seen great work flying past the ears of the audience because the speaker was too technical, but I've also seen technical people labeling research as "easy" because the speaker avoided technical details.
- a good talk can be heard by a future employer (especially in academia) and they would sometimes offer the speaker a job in their lab, especially if the speaker mentions that he's looking for a position;
- a talk at a conference can also mean a chance to disseminate good quality research that would otherwise be buried in the pages of journal (even a good one);
- in places where scientists are quite isolated from the international community, conference attendance and talks help break that isolation, and even start collaborations with other researchers;
- I personally like giving talks only to give a chance to researchers I won't otherwise meet to comment on my work and even give some helpful suggestions. It is often that the discussion continues after the session ended or at the dinner table.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the conference. Contact the chair and speak to your colleagues to ask what benefit you might gain from attending the conference.

Some conferences, though in my experience in the humanities and social sciences, just ask for an abstract (a few hundred words) outlining the contribution of the intended talk. In those conferences, they pick which talks to have based on the abstracts. Then, after the conference, they invite a number of the best talks to write up their work as an article to be published in a journal.

In my field, computer science, most conferences require you to write a whole paper (usually 4-10 pages, depending on the conference and the size of your research contribution) to be able to give a talk at the conference. As @JenB says, most academic institutions will only pay for their research staff to go to a conference if they have published a paper there.

Now, some of the conferences that require a whole paper, will require an abstract to be submitted a week or two before the paper deadline. This is normally for logistical reasons, so they can pre-allocate which reviewers will review each paper.

- *Why might one want to go to a conference?* To learn about the state of the art in this research field, and to network with the other researchers in the field, to maybe form collaborations.
- *Why might a researcher want to publish and present at a conference?* To disseminate their work, get feedback from their peers, to promote their institution, and also for the reasons above.
- *Why might a employee of a company want to present at a conference?* (I've not been in this situation, so take with a pinch of salt!) To disseminate their work (as much as their company allows), to promote their company, and also for the reasons above.
- *Why might an academic conference want industry attendees and presenters?* To help cross-pollinate the work of academia and industry, so they can both learn from each other. To enable networking and industrial collaborations. To facilitate partnerships that might bring industrial money into academic research projects, or gain access to research council funding that requires industrial collaboration.

Comment: +1 since for some conference, the "abstract" you're submitting is the whole thing, just in a very concise form and perhaps missing some of the minor-but-longer details.

Answer (score 2):

All of the other answers are correct, but may also be missing the fundamental misunderstanding here. Academic conferences are not like (some) commercial conferences, in that there is not an existing programme - perhaps of invited industry figures - that these talks add to. The talks that come from these abstracts are the *only*, or at least the main, content of the conference.

Perhaps more significantly, wheras at many commercial conferences the goal is networking, and the programme of presentations is of minor importance (a cynic might day that it is mostly there to provide an excuse to attend that will satisfy the accountants), at academic conferences people are actually there for the talks - although of course networking can be an important component too.